# Unable to locate package mongodb-org on Debian

Tags: mongodb, debian, apt-get

I'm trying to install MongoDB 3.0 on my Debian server (wheezy) 32 bit and I can't figure out what's gone wrong despite the fact that I followed the [MongoDB install Tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/#install-mongodb):

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
apt-get update
apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

The fourth command still failing even if the others are successful:

```
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
```

I've found subjects of this matter on Stackoverflow but it was on Ubuntu so, ...

EDIT:

`lsb_release -sc` gives `wheezy`

NO APT-GET SOLUTION:

Get the Linux 32-bit Legacy version of MongoDB [here](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads):

```
wget https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-i686-3.0.2.tgz
tar zxvf mongodb-linux-i686-3.0.2.tgz
cp mongodb-linux-i686-3.0.2.tgz/bin/* /usr/bin
```

Don't forget to change ownership/permissions.

Comment: are you on 32bit machine or 64?

Comment: I'm on a 32 bit machine

Comment: Please open a shell and give us the output of `lsb_release -sc`.

Comment: `wheezy` is the result of `lsb_release -sc`

Comment: This worked for me (but using jessie) although the service configuration etc. isn't set up, not clear how this should be done.

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb
```

I spent 2 hrs on the same problem on clean Debian x64. just try. this.

Comment: its a different version. Why is that even the case. Very annoying to look for the one and have people suggesting the other one.

Comment: @TheFool Version of what? `Asked 5 years` - now it's about different versions for sure.

Comment: no `mongodb` and  `mongodb-org` are two different things. That was five years ago the case and that is still the case. Most people dont care or dont realize because they dont use it to interoperate with other mongodbs. Then you get trouble using the wrong package.

Comment: Sad that it is still the case. I moved to Ubuntu because of it, and I'm actually happy about it today. :3

Answer (score 1):

As you can verify by visiting

http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/dists/wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0/main/binary-i386/

there are no packages there, in contrast to

http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/dists/wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0/main/binary-amd64/

I do not know why this is the case, but one option is to build the packages from source in your i386 machine.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. The solution i found is to `wget` the Linux 32-bit Legacy version then extract the `/bin` folder in the `mongodb-linux-i686-3.0.2.tgz` into `usr/bin`

Answer (score 1):

I litle late but:

```
wget http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/dists/wheezy/mongodb-org/3.4/main/binary-amd64/{package_vesion}
sudo dpkg -i {package_version}
```

But I could not found the x86 version, only x86_64.

Answer (score -3):

I used a normal root command `apt-get install mongodb-org`  without the `-y` option
P.S: that works for Debian 9 too